# Windows 7 automatically adjusting volume (normal fix does not work)

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

Windows keeps automatically lowering music volume when other sounds play. For example, while playing a game or watching a video and something loud happens (such as an explosion), the music volume dips. After the loud sounds stop or I tab out of the game, the music returns to its previous volume.

Fixes I have already tried (and had no luck with):

- Ticking the 'Do Nothing' option in the Communications tab
- Unticking 'Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device' in the Advanced tab of my speakers (Playback tab) and sound card (Recording tab)
- Ticking/unticking 'Disable all sound effects' in the Enhancements tab of my speakers (Playback tab) and sound card (Recording tab)
- Disabling 'Sound Check' and 'Sound Enhancer' in iTunes

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: @and31415 I seem to, yes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the application that has this problem.
2. Ensure it has sound output like for a video player, play a video. It won't work only by opening the video player.
3. Then click on the Speaker icon in the notification bar (If you are in any game, then switch to desktop. Do not close the game.).
4. Click on 'Mixer', then change the sound of the application.

Check if it may be happening due to the sound card.

Comment: The levels on the Volume Mixer do not change on their own (all remain at 100), and altering them (eg reducing them and pushing them back up to 100) doesn't affect the issue. I should also probably mention, it's not like a massive reduction of volume, it's just enough to be noticeable.